# Referencing the correct System.Windows.Interactivity dll from Prism application

Tags: wpf, prism, expression-blend

I have a WPF Prism application that I'm building.  The application is to the point where  I want to be able to add EventTriggers to controls so I can call commands on the underlying view model.  However,  I can't seem to reference the correct DLLs to make the project run.  Currently, I'm referencing `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions` and `System.Windows.Interactivity` from the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.0\Libraries` directory.

When I run the module, I get this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Interactivity,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

I checked the `System.Windows.Interactivity` assembly in reflector and can see that it references:

- mscorlib
- PresentationCore
- PresentationFramework
- System
- System.Core
- System.Xaml
- WindowsBase

All the references point to the 4.0 framework.  I've referenced each from the .NET reference tab, making sure that each one is the 4.0 version.  All these references are being loaded from the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0` directory.

Is there another download I need for the `System.Windows.Interactivity` and `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions` assemblies to work in my environment?

Comment: Have you set 'copy local' to true in the properties of the System.Windows.Interactivity reference?

Comment: All assemblies are set to copy local and that still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I have shared my experience to a similar problem. Please refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/33592411/1912383

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For some reason that I still cannot fathom, Prism includes it's own version of the Blend SDK assemblies.  So you should reference Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll and System.Windows.Interactivity.dll from the Lib\Desktop folder of the Prism distribution (assuming you're using Prism v4) rather than from the Blend SDK installation.

Answer (score 6):

For people landing on this page experiencing this problem but where the above given solution isn't working, you might have a look at: [Prism assembly reference failure: System.Windows.Interactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650778/prism-assembly-reference-failure-system-windows-interactivity)