# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Expression.Interactions and GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, prism-4

I am facing unknown problem while using Prism 4.  We implement business solution in MVVM pattern. For that I have used

```
 1. Microsoft.Expression.Interactions

 2. System.Windows.Interactivity

 3. GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4
```

for Interaction.Triggers, CallMethodAction and EventToCommand.

```
<SWI:Interaction.Triggers>
    <SWI:EventTrigger SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=txtName}" EventName="GotFocus">
        <MEI:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding Path=DataContext,ElementName=txtName}" MethodName="txtName_GotFocus"></MEI:CallMethodAction>
    </SWI:EventTrigger>
    <SWI:EventTrigger SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=txtName}" EventName="KeyUp">
        <GMEWCMD:EventToCommand   Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.cmdtxtNameKeyUpEvent,ElementName=txtName}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True">
        </GMEWCMD:EventToCommand>
    </SWI:EventTrigger>
</SWI:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Everything is working fine but now we required to make whole system loosely couple we choose prism 4.  We already achieved this but above code create following problem as below.

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Expression.Interactions, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

If I comment above code everything is working fine. I don't know what an issue. Does PRISM 4 not support above assemblies?

Please help us to get rid from this problem.

Thank you

Comment: Having very similar issue, but not using Prism.

Answer (score 14):

This commonly happens to me when I reference both Microsoft.Expression.Interactions and System.Windows.Interactivity in a view that belongs to a module, but I fail to also add those references to the project that acts as the shell.

Comment: @franssu it means - add those references to application not only library

Comment: I don't know if this was the answer for the OP, but it was for me.

Comment: Worked for me, too

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Prism in Visual Studio 2012. The XAML editor would fail with the same exception.

The solution was to install [Microsoft Expression Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=10801). The assembly should be part of SDK. Allegedly, it is necessary for binding between control events and commands in XAML and some code may require it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem during a Prism 6.1 composite app using .NET 4.5.2, where i was referencing in one of the modules (class library) the  Microsoft.Expression.Interactions & System.Windows.Interactivity. 
Eventually i had to reference the same dlls in the Desktop project (where bootstrapper and Shell belong)