# Could not load file or assembly from referenced namespace

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to create a ressource in my page of a type defined in another namespace. but on compile, I get an error "Could not load file or assembly 'Hero.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies."
What's strange is that intellissence is helping me choose my namespace. The reference is added to my project, I can use the classes in code behind.

Can anyone tell me what's missing? Thanks

Here's my code so far (The last line is giving me the error):

```
<Page
    x:Name="pageRoot"
    x:Class="Hero.Metro.Home"
    DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Hero.Metro"
    xmlns:VM="using:Hero.ViewModel"
    xmlns:common="using:Hero.Metro.Common"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <common:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>

        <VM:RacesList x:Key="RacesList"/>
```

Comment: Try rebuilding the solution. Intellisense will often find content in other referenced projects that it expects to be in a given DLL, but haven't been actually successfully built yet.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that.
Clean, Rebuild, Close VS. Clean, Rebuild, I still have the same error.
If I do a go to definition on the 'VM:RacesList VS send me to the right place...

Comment: I'm using 2013 Preview. So it might be a bug in the software. But since I'm pretty new to XAML, I'm guessing it's my syntax that is missing something.

Comment: Does your RacesList have a default constructor? Is it in a Portable/Class Library or in the same solution?

Comment: It does have a default constructor and it's in a PCL project in the same solution.

Comment: Maybe check somewhere in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650778/prism-assembly-reference-failure-system-windows-interactivity)?

Comment: Maybe, but I don't understand much of the code. Also, I'm not using Prism but rather the portable class library project built-in.

For now I'll do my binding in the code behind but I'll keep the question open in case someone find a way.

Thanks again.

Comment: That question actually revolved around the Interactivity PCL, which is one of the reasons I linked it. It may be that the issue with your PCL is the same that they had with the one installed via Nuget.

Comment: Here's the real thing to take away: Is your App referencing all of the same DLL's that your PCL is? So, if your PCL is using Mvvm Light, is your App using the same version?

Answer (score 0):

Replace 
from

```
xmlns:VM="using:Hero.ViewModel"
```

to

```
xmlns:VM="using:ViewModel"
```

I had the same problem