# Using Prism in Non-Prism Application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, prism

I'm developing Visual Studio Extensions. For the UI parts I use WPF and now I stumbled across Prism and found that it brings some features that I really want (like the [InteractionRequests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405494%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx)), because they make ViewModels testable. Problem is, I don't seem to get it to work.

I installed the Prism NuGet-Bundle on my project. Then I implemented a window with a button that fires an InteractionRequest and assigned a trigger to that request. This worked. I debugged into the action that the trigger invokes.

However, after some Cleans and Rebuilds I now always run into "Couldn't load System.Windows.Interactivity". This seems to be [a known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650778/prism-assembly-reference-failure-system-windows-interactivity) and the answers imply that what I try to do is not possible. However, why did it work at first?

Is it possible to use Prism in a Non-Prism Application, like in a Visual Studio Extension? How?
If not, is there an alternative way to achieve something like interaction requests?

Comment: Do you have a small sample to share? That way I would be able to get better understanding on the scenario you mention, and I would try to troubleshoot the issue. Regards.

Comment: I removed Prism from my project and replicated the logic needed for the InteractionRequests, since it's not too much. But I'll try to assemble a minimal example that shows the issue by the end of this week. May be interesting for others or myself in the future ;)

Comment: I'll not manage to create the example today. I'm on vacation next week, so it take more time, sorry...