# Why is `Systems.Windows.Interactivity` unavailable when Microsoft Blend SDK is installed?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

One of my projects contains a reference to "System.Windows.Interactivity"

```
<Reference Include="System.Windows.Interactivity, Version=4.0.0.0, 
   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
   <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
</Reference>
```

I've installed Microsoft Expression Blend SDK for Silverlight 4 and so the file exists and is available at this location:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\Silverlight\v4.0\Libraries\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll

However I still receive the following error while building:

> The tag 'Interaction.Triggers' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity'.

I don't know what else can I do other than installing Blend SDK. How do I fix my problem?

Comment: is the namespace assigned in the projects reference folder ?

Comment: @MarkHall i'm sorry i don't understand your question

Comment: In your solution explorer, click the All Files Icon on the top, open your project, you should see a References folder open it up and make sure that System.Windows.Interactivity is in there. If not right click on the Folder, select add reference and add it.

Comment: @MarkHall yes it there, I posted in my question my reference from project file. this is the same reference that displayed in Solution Explorer

Comment: @MarkHall but icon is followed with "!" displaying that reference can not be resolved, and my question - why?

Comment: try removing it and adding it again, that error usaully means that the path changed or the file is no longer where it was originally

Comment: This problem is gone but another arise `Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.`

Comment: See if anything in this [Bing search](http://www.bing.com/search?q=Cannot+resolve+dependency+to+assembly+%27System.Windows%2C+Version%3D2.0.5.0&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=cannot+resolve+dependency+to+assembly+%27system.windows%2C+version%3D2.0.5.0&sc=0-0&sp=-1&sk=) helps you

Comment: @MarkHall yeap I've found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286774/referencing-the-correct-system-windows-interactivity-dll-from-prism-application and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253740/unknown-build-error-cannot-resolve-dependency-to-system-windows so probably I reference wrong dll...

Comment: @MarkHall however i don't have Prism appliation, just normal WPF application...

Comment: I think the long and short of it, is you can not use a silverlight dll in a Wpf project.

Comment: @MarkHall right I was using wrong SDK. need to use "for .NET 4" version, not "for Silverlight 4" version. thanks, my problem is resolved!